# NGINX Rewriting subdomains as URL in a proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I would like to redirect specifc subdomains of my domain to my backend as 
prefixes of the URL that is passed to the backend. This is because I have a single server and I do not want to have to handle the multiple domains in the backend due to increased complexity.

Hence if I have:

- `sub1.domain.com` => `domain.com/sub1/`
- `sub1.domain.com/pathname` => `domain.com/sub1/pathname`
- `sub1.domain.com/pathname?searchquery` => `domain.com/pathname?searchquery`

and so forth.

So far what I have come up with is the following:

```
server {
  charset utf8;
  listen 80;
  server_name
    domain.com,
    sub1.domain.com,
    sub2.domain.com,
    sub3.domain.com,
    sub4.domain.com,
    sub5.domain.com;

  # Default
  if ($host ~ ^domain\.com) {
    set $proxy_uri $request_uri;
  }
  # Rewrites
  if ($host ~ (.*)\.domain\.com) {
    set $proxy_uri $1$request_uri;
  }

  location / {
    expires 1s;
    proxy_pass http://node:8080$proxy_uri; #node is an internally listed host (docker container)
    proxy_set_header Host domain.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
  }
}
```

But unfortunately all I get is a 502: Bad Gateway with the following log, `2017/06/11 12:49:18 [error] 6#6: *2 no resolver defined to resolve node, client: 136.0.0.110, server: domain.com:8888,, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "sub1.domain.com:8888", referrer: "http://sub1.domain.com:8888/"` Any idea how I can achieve my goal? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I wasn't so far from the answer - adding an upstream block before the server block was sufficient to finalize the config to the desired effect.

```
upstream backend {
  server node:8080;
  keepalive 8;
}
```

I also had to slightly modify the proxy pass line to the following:

```
proxy_pass http://backend$proxy_uri;
```

The problem must likely have been one related to how NGINX parses the proxy pass urls - if anyone reading this can provide an insight into the reason, please edit this answer!